# Visual Studio 2015 missing android emulator

Tags: android, c++, android-emulator, cross-platform, visual-studio-2015

After installing Visual Studio 2015 Preview, I've checked android emulator when second installer prompt, but when I create a new android project, there are no android emulator option with X86, only a start button is exist...

[image]

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update as per comment below: You need Hyper-V enabled on your machine to run the VS Emulator for Android.

Sorry, I cannot tell from your blurry screenshot if this is a C++ or a Cordova or a Xamarin project in VS2015. In any case can you try with the other project type to see if this is a project type issue or an emulator issue?

Also I presume you have all the requirements such as Hyper-V enabled, correct? You can read more about the VS Emulator for Android and its requirements here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/introducing-visual-studio-s-emulator-for-android.aspx

Comment: Hey Daniel, Thanks for the reply...
I was testing C++ for Cross Platform Mobile Development with Visual Studio 2015. I've no problem with Cordova project, only matters with C++ Cross Platform Project.
I've solved the problem with re-install visual studio 2015 Preview...
But here it's come to another problem, my laptop doesn't allow me to have Hyper-V, is there any alternative software/program can replace it?

Comment: Sorry, Hyper-V is required, there is no working around that :-(